# PyQGIS - Adding layer from PostGis database

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, database, connection

I want to add new layer from PostGIS database but this code isn't working... Can someone help me?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("IP address", "5432", "ruian", "user", "pass", QgsDataSourceURI.SSLdisable)
uri.setDataSource("public", "okresy.originalnihranice", "MultiPolygon", "", "ogc_fid")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "okresy", "postgres")

if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer %s did not load" % layer.name()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

layer is always empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into this post [Empty layer after import into PostGIS Database. Pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/247114/35779)

The user mentioned to

> make sure that you are looking at using `psycopg2` python module. This should have been installed when you got PostgreSQL and PostGIS in your system.
>
> created my new user with privileges of superuser for being able to add postgis extension in new database
>
> use pgadmin3 to create a new connection and to add postgis extension to this database.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I just solved my probem. I had to split name of table "okresy" and "originalnihranice".