# Loading table from Postgres database using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to load a table in QGIS layers tree using PyQGIS (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257939/pyqgis-adding-layer-from-postgis-database) for example). Said table has got a primary key with no null/duplicate entries; a geometry column (which is empty for now); and works perfectly fine when I load it using QGIS database manager.

But, when I try to load it using PyQGIS, the layer does not load correctly: there's a /!\ next to its name in QGIS layers tree, and `print(myLayer.isValid()`) returns `False`. And I can't figure out what is wrong with my code...

Here is my code so far (host, bdd, password etc.. have been defined as global variables earlier in the code):

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(host, port, bdd, user, password, QgsDataSourceUri.SslDisable)
uri.setDataSource("ref", "grds_types_milieux","empty_geom","")
myLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "grds_types_milieux", "postgres") 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(myLayer)
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate, maybe this function can help you. https://github.com/bstroebl/DataDrivenInputMask/blob/43beaeba4cdb020e668237df9318ecfa7a81ab15/ddmanager.py#L802

Answer (score 1):

Made it work by :

- recreating my table with the primary key column in first position
- renaming my geometry column to "geom" (also, it's the last column; but I don't know if this matters)
- giving the name of the primary key column in the code :

  uri.setDataSource("ref", "grds_types_milieux","geom","","id")